# vuejs custom filter not working probably

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making an SPA using laravel and VueJS. In the front I need to have a category functionality where the user is able to filter posts via category, as a result I have to use VueJS cutsom filters.

Here is what I've written:

```
Vue.filter('cat', function (contacts) {
    var selectedcat = this.category;
    if(!selectedcat) return this.contacts;
    return contacts.filter(function(contact){
        return selectedcat == contact.category.name;
    });
```

And here is my Contacts object:

[image: my contact object]

Comment: if you are making a SPA, you should consider a more matured framework like ember or angular (1.3, not 2.0) instead of vuejs

Comment: your filter uses `this` but filters can't acces `this`. i suggest remove  `this` and add argument for `category`